# How to take backup of functions only in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to take backup of all functions in my postgres database.How to take backup of functions only in Postgres?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

use `pg_getfunctiondef`; see [system information functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html). `pg_getfunctiondef` was added in PostgreSQL 8.4.

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef('proc_name'::regproc);
```

To dump all functions in a schema you can query the system tables in `pg_catalog`; say if you wanted everything from `public`:

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef(f.oid)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc f
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (f.pronamespace = n.oid)
WHERE n.nspname = 'public';
```

it's trivial to change the above to say *"from all schemas except those beginning with `pg_`"* instead if that's what you want.

In `psql` you can dump this to a file with:

```
psql -At dbname > /path/to/output/file.sql <<"__END__"
... the above SQL ...
__END__
```

To run the output in another DB, use something like:

```
psql -1 -v ON_ERROR_STOP -f /path/to/output/file.sql target_db_name
```

If you're replicating functions between DBs like this, though, consider storing the authorative copy of the function definitions as a SQL script in a revision control system like svn or git, preferably packaged as a PostgreSQL extension. See [packaging extensions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html).

Comment: Also i want to restore these functions to another db.How can i do that??.Functions only need to restore

Comment: @vmb The output is SQL function definitions, so pipe them into psql. See updated answer. Even better, create an extension and package them in it.

Comment: It should be noted, that `pg_get_functiondef('proc_name'::regproc)` **DOES NOT** dump the function's privileges (`GRANT` and `REVOKE` statements) which may be sometimes considered as part of the function definition.

Comment: This answer is great: by far the best option I looked at. It helped us in dumping our nearly 400 functions into a reliable backup file as well as to use for revision history. To do that, at the end the of the query I added an order by: ```ORDER BY pg_get_functiondef(f.oid)```  Thanks!

Comment: Note this will not dump aggregate functions. It will produce an error (`"ERROR: X is an aggregate function"`). You need to add `and f.proisagg is false` to exclude those.

Comment: SELECT pg_get_functiondef(oid)  
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc  
where pronamespace in (select oid from pg_catalog.pg_namespace where nspname = 'public');

Comment: I had to skip aggregate functions. So, I had to add "and f.proname not like '%agg%';" at the end of the "where" clause

Comment: @cerd In PostgreSQL 11 `proisagg` was replaced with `prokind`: `AND f.prokind = 'f'`

Comment: @egofer To clarify, `WHERE proisagg` would be repaced with `prokind = 'a'` ; since you want _non_ aggregates you use `WHERE prokind <> 'f'`. If you use `WHERE prokind = 'f'` instead, you'll omit window functions which you probably want to capture. I don't know why `pg_get_functiondef()` doesn't just output definitions for aggregates too; presumably you have to do that yourself by joining on `pg_aggregate` instead.

Answer (score 38):

You can't tell `pg_dump` to dump only functions.  However, you can make a dump without data (`-s` or `--schema-only`) and filter it on restoring.  Note the `--format=c` (also `-Fc`) part: this will produce a file suitable for `pg_restore`.

First take the dump:

```
pg_dump -U username --format=c --schema-only -f dump_test your_database
```

Then create a list of the functions:

```
pg_restore --list dump_test | grep FUNCTION > function_list
```

And finally restore them (`-L` or `--use-list` specifies the list file created above):

```
pg_restore -U username -d your_other_database -L function_list dump_test
```

Comment: Seems you can only get public function this way. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57581710/pg-dump-excluded-functions

Comment: @ShiheZhang nope.  Laurenz there is using `-n public` explicitly to dump the public schema only.