# How to take functions backup in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to backup the functions in database using the method described here [How to take backup of functions only in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758003/how-to-take-backup-of-functions-only-in-postgres). 
But it is showing error `<< was unexpected at this time`.

The code I typed in the command prompt is given below.

```
psql.exe -U postgres -At dbname > /path/to/output/file.sql <<"__END__"
SELECT pg_get_functiondef(f.oid)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc f
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (f.pronamespace = n.oid)
WHERE n.nspname = 'public';
__END__
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't think you want the quotes around "\_\_END\_\_"

Comment: @Loopo         It is showing the same error message.

Comment: also, you could try adding -c just in front of your input redirection ... so ...file.sql -c <<\_\_END\_\_ ....

Comment: @Loopo         Still not working.

Comment: just put it all on one line and use -c: `psql.exe -U postgres -At dbname -c "your multi-line sql as one line" > /path/to/output/file.sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shell problem.

<< is a feature of Unix-like shells, while you seem to be using Windows.

Just save the text of the query into a file and run it with the -f flag.

Comment: I placed the query in a text file and used psql -U postgres -d databasename -f D:\q
uery.sql >D:/file.sql

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a way to do it, but the simplest thing is just supply the sql as one line with the `-c` option:

```
psql.exe -U postgres -At dbname -c "SELECT pg_get_functiondef(f.oid) FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc f INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (f.pronamespace = n.oid) WHERE n.nspname = 'public'" > /path/to/output/file.sql
```

This is also more portable and will work with tools that need one line, like cron etc