# pg_dump excluded functions

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I created a pg_dump with the following command -

```sh
pg_dump -U postgres -d db -n public \
   --exclude-table-data 'exclude_table_*' \
   --exclude-table-data 'another_set_of_tables_to_exclude*' > dump.sql
```

This excluded the tables I needed it to exclude, but it didn't dump any functions that were in the `public` schema. Why did it not dump the functions and how do I get it to dump them?

**UPDATE**

This is the definition of a materialized view -

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW public.attending AS
SELECT (split_part((ct.id)::text, '-'::text, 1))::bigint AS 
attending_physician,
split_part((ct.id)::text, '-'::text, 2) AS business,
(split_part((ct.id)::text, '-'::text, 3))::bigint AS organization,
split_part((ct.id)::text, '-'::text, 4) AS county,
ct.id,
ct."qtr-0",
ct."qtr-1",
ct."qtr-2",
ct."qtr-3",
ct."qtr-4",
ct."qtr-5",
ct."qtr-6",
ct."qtr-7",
ct."qtr-8" 
FROM crosstab('SELECT attending_practitioner || ''-'' || business || ''-'' || organization || ''-'' || county AS id, period, COALESCE(admits, 0) 
FROM   calc ORDER  BY 1, 2 DESC'::text, 'SELECT year || ''q'' || quarter FROM calc_trend ORDER BY 1 DESC limit 9'::text) ct(id character varying(32), "qtr-0" integer, "qtr-1" integer, "qtr-2" integer, "qtr-3" integer, "qtr-4" integer, "qtr-5" integer, "qtr-6" integer, "qtr-7" integer, "qtr-8" integer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should dump functions (and all other objects) in the `public` schema.

The functions that are *not* dumped are those that are part of an extension, like the `crosstab` in your case. Such objects are not dumped individually, they are included in the `CREATE EXTENSION`.

Unfortunately extensions are not dumped with a schema dump (they belong to the database).

You should create the extensions manually on the destination database before restoring the dump:

```
CREATE EXTENSION crosstab;
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the definition of the mat view.

Comment: It is like I suspected. I have extended the answer.

Comment: So, is `crosstab` a custom thing that the author of the view wrote?

Comment: `crosstab` is an extension that is shipped with PostgreSQL in the "contrib" modules.