# How to get dump only function creation & Stored Process script via command line in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am able to get the script for table creation via pg_dump command in postgress sql similar way I need to generate for functions, SP's & views to export into SQL file via pg_dump.

Can you please help on this?

For a Table:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -d postgres  -t clientlocationregions > C:\clientlocationregions.sql
```

Thanks
Mahesh

Comment: You might want to check following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758003/how-to-take-backup-of-functions-only-in-postgres

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take backup of functions only in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758003/how-to-take-backup-of-functions-only-in-postgres)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
pg_dump -Fc -s -n <schemaname> -f temp.dump <database name>
pg_restore -l temp.dump | grep FUNCTION > functionalist
pg_restore -L functionalist temp.dump > yourfunctions.sql
```