# Except for pg_dump What else can I do to backup a postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump

Except for pg_dump What else can I do to backup a postgreSQL database.Pg_dump shoul run in postgresql server,but i only konw the database connection info.

I try to use sql to do this.But there are to much things to backeup,such as  tables,squences,function and so on .so i want to known is there any other thing to help me to backup postgresql.

Comment: Hey, pg_dump itself can handle taking backups of various things in PostgreSQL, like tables, sequences, functions, views, and many more. So, when you use pg_dump with the appropriate options, you can create a full backup for all the objects within the specified schema.

Try checking things more specifically.
 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758003/how-to-take-backup-of-functions-only-in-postgres

Comment: You can use pg_dump from any (virtual) machine that is allowed to connect to your database server. Just install it and make your first backup.

Answer (score 0):

You seem confused about pg_dump and how it operates. I suggest reading the online manuals.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html